# Send data from Server to Client without Collections (with Websocket)

Tags: meteor, websocket, ddp

I'm currently working on a WebApp in Meteor. There is a Server, a Web Client (a browser) and another client which is a C application.
I've made a connection between my C app and the Server using Websocket. Everything work fine I got connected and I can get data from the Server and call RPC (Remote Procedure Call) from the client.

I actually need to call some RPC from the Server to the C app. I know I can use Collections in order to dialog with my C app but it's not very suitable...

I wonder if there is a way to use the current Websocket connection in order to send my own messages to the C client.

Comment: Have you thought of implementing a DDP server in the C app and have two DDP connections in both directions? This might be an overkill, though.

Comment: This would be useful but very heavy. Moreover, there is no implementation of Meteor in C, so it implies a lot of work for small benefits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your findings, DDP RPC is a way for the client to call arbitrary methods on a server, but there's no RPC facility from the server to the client.

A Meteor publication should do what you want, though. You can use the [low-level `added`/`changed`/`removed` interface](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) to send arbitrary data to subscribed clients whenever for whatever reason. You probably only have to implement, say `added`. Let's assume you do this.

The client can do whatever it wants with these data. It just needs to call `sub`, then it will start receiving your `added` messages.

[This code](https://github.com/alexhancock/ddp-cpp) might be a decent starting point. Again, if you only ever send and look for `added`, you only need to implement that one bit on the server and client.

Comment: It seems I don't have a lot of options... I can do that or I create a new Websocket in parallels to send custom messages (and it's not what I want). Thank you for your help :)

Comment: actually you can use the DDP connection and just "write" to it, in other words, send your own messages instead of a DDP message. I remember seeing this on a tutorial, something like ".write" on the sockjs object, but i can't find it. ( i'm looking for it now as well ).